# How to change appcompat autocomplete popup text color?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I know there is a lot of questions, with answers, but none of them works for me.

My styles and themes:

```
<style name="AnnaTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--
    Colors,
    and stuff
    -->
    <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/DropDownItemStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/DropDownItemStyle</item>
    <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/DropDownItemStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownItemStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

But the result is still this:

[image: White dropdown]

The layout is this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/et_email"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/join_field_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And the adapter:

```
emailView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Utils.getUniqueEmailsFromAccount(this)));
```

Can you guys help me how to make the text black?

Comment: Try `android:popupBackground="#000000"` on your AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: By the way how did you declare your AutoCompleteTextView can you put the java ?

Comment: I don't want black background, but black text. I also added the code for adapter.

Comment: It changes textcolor of the text field, not the popup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this advice then...

*First try to change your `Adapter` to this (if it didn't work try with the second option :*

`emailView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Utils.getUniqueEmailsFromAccount(this)));`

---

1# Create a `style` as follows :

```
<style name="CustomAuto">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
</style>
```

2# Create a `Layout` as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/any_id"
style="@style/CustomAuto"
android:singleLine="true" />
```

3# Change your `Adapter` to :

```
emailView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.text_custom_view, Utils.getUniqueEmailsFromAccount(this)));
```

Comment: First, I want text color of popup, not background. Changing this to getBaseContext() did nothing. And changing the textColor as you suugests changes text color of EditText, not the popup.

Comment: android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: With support library, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item is even better.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be creating your own list item. So, create a layout XML file and write the following codes there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And pass it to the adapter's constructor.

```
emailView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.that_layout, Utils.getUniqueEmailsFromAccount(this)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the Adapter:

```
emailView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Utils.getUniqueEmailsFromAccount(this))){  
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            return view;

        }};
```